# Windows Update with low free space

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I am trying to update my Windows 10 installation on my tablet and I am having problems due to the limited storage available.

I am unable to update as Windows Update is complaining that there is not enough space on `C:\` drive, even though I have a 128GB SD card with plenty of space available.

[image: Windows Update Screenshot]

Is there any way I can update my Windows installation or am I now stuck?

Comment: Check if it is useful this link about [Compact OS, single-instancing, and image optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn940129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...

Comment: @magicandre1981 I already have Windows 10, I'm not trying to upgrade from Windows 8.1.

Comment: this looks like you try to update from TH1 to TH2 which is technically the same like going from 8.1 to 10

Comment: Microsoft released a fix to improve upgrade on devices with low storage: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/a-fix-is-released-to-improve-disk-space/f6c6d3f0-fb27-41e1-b6eb-c6bf4a39aa6e?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

I also have a tablet with 16GB on-board (eMMC) memory, and I was able to successfully upgrade to Windows 10 using the following tweaks:

- Run Disk Clean-up as indicated in the dialog box.
- Disable hibernation (which in turn removes the hiberfil.sys file) by running the following command in an administrator command window:
  `powercfg -h -off`
- Manually configure the paging file to be quite small (e.g. 128MB. Do not disable it completely!), or, if possible, move it to the SD card. You can do this in Advanced System Settings.

This should free up quite a few gigabytes.

Comment: I have tried all 3 of these steps and it hasn't resulted in any additional space being freed, and Windows Update is still complaining. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: OK. Well you can select drive D (SD card) for the additional space that Windows requires for the installation. Or use an USB stick if you don't want to use the SD card. Windows will still be installed on C:\, only it's backup data (windows.old) will go to the drive that you selected. That data is only needed if you ever want to roll back the installation.

Comment: I have selected drive D (as shown in the image) and it is still demanding more space on C:/?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you might want to try refreshing your PC to wipe all user files and return it to factory state. This will hopefully give you a clean system with as much free space as possible.

Naturally you should first back up all personal files to an external drive (preferably two). Additionally save a system image to an external drive.

Then go to system settings > reset this PC